# How would I implement my present threads into an AsyncTask to make the UI respond better?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

For my activities to work, I have to get data from the internet.

I implemented threads, but I am not that good with Java or threads yet, so I kinda rushed through it just hoping it would work. Well it works, but the UI feels slow sometimes because it takes awhile until the activity appears.

Here is my code

an activity, lets call it MainActivity calls:

```
JSONObject Data = WebApi.getData(id);
```

the class WebApi pieces the url together:

```
public static JSONObject getData(String id) {

    String url  = URL;
           url += DATA_URL;     
           url += VALUE_DATA_ID + id;

    return WebInterface.executeWeb(url);               
}
```

and hands it over to WebInterface, in WebInterface the whole thing gets executed:

```
public static String getUrl(final String url) {

    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() 
            {

            try 
            {
                InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                String result, line = reader.readLine();
                result = line;
                while((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
                    result+=line;
                }

                sb.append(result);


            } catch (Exception e)
            {
            // TODO: handle exception
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
      });   

    thread.start();

    try {
        thread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String result = sb.toString();
    Log.d(App.TAG, result);

    return result;

}       

public static JSONObject executeWeb(final String url) {

    String result = WebInterface.getUrl(url);

    JSONObject json = null;

    try {
        json = new JSONObject(result.trim());

    } catch (JSONException e) {

        try {
            json = new JSONObject("{}");
        } catch (JSONException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return json;                

}
```

well this works but i feel like this would work even better, if I would implement it with ASyncTask. My Activity could show some cached data until the "real" data appears. Would that be possible with AsyncTask? And would I need to redo a lot of my code for that?

thanks in advance for the help!

Edit:

thanks to whoever suggested AsyncTaskLoader (i think that one deleted his answer)
I did it with AsyncTaskLoader, very handy and very easy!

Comment: I'm not sure why you think you need to change it. If you were going to show some cached data with an `AsyncTask` then why can't you without?

Comment: @codeMagic he suggests to show cached data and later the fresh fetched one but his current implementation does not load cached data. I would recommend to check Loader and LoaderManager to load the stuff you need in background. It does the AsyncTask stuff for you.

Comment: I would implement the caching mechanism myself. I just dont know how to do the asynctask

Answer (score 3):

In effect your code is single threaded because of thread.join(). The current thread just waits for the newly spawned thread to finish. You have in effect not removed the network from the main thread, hence the UI "locks up" or feels slow.

You could have a callback that runs on the main thread when your thread is finished, but AsyncTask does this for you, and allows you to update a progress bar properly if desired. Read the documentation on how to implement AsyncTask.

Comment: I know thats why I asked how would I do that with an Asynctask

Answer (score 0):

svenoaks is correct that your use of `thread.join()` is making your code effectively single threaded.  His solution of using an [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) is also correct.

An alternative approach is to use a [`Handler`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) in conjunction with the threads you already have.  Create the Handler on your main thread, then in the spawned thread [`obtain()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Message.html#obtain%28%29) a new message and use the handler to [send](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#sendMessage%28android.os.Message%29) it.  You then have code in the handler (which executes on the main thread) that receives the message and updates the UI.

Comment: I know I already suggested in my question that I need an AsyncTask

Comment: So what's stopping you?  Do some research, read some tutorials and get started.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more of your code I can't be sure what it is you want to do with the data, but I can give you a basic example of how to use an AsyncTask. First you won't need any of that Thread stuff in getUrl(), so lets get rid of it. getUrl() should look something like this:

```
public static String getUrl(String url) {

    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();


    try 
    {
        InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String result, line = reader.readLine();
        result = line;
        while((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
            result+=line;
        }

        sb.append(result);


    } catch (Exception e)
    {
    // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    String result = sb.toString();

    return result;

}
```

Next lets wrap your call to WebApi.getData in an AsyncTask, so that it runs in the background.

```
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, JSONObject>(){

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(Void... params) {
            JSONObject data = WebApi.getData(id);
            return data;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result){
            //here you can do something with result
        }

    }.execute();
```

AsynTask will execute whatever code is in doInBackground() in a background thread, and then return the result to onPostExecute(), which will be run on the UI thread. Please note id will have to be declared final in the example I gave above.

As has already been said, you should probably read the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) on AsyncTask.